# Any .NET IDE running on Windows Mobile?

Tags: .net, ide, windows-mobile, editor, intellisense

Is there any .NET IDE running on windows Mobile 6.x? The IDE does not have to support mobile development, nor debugging or something else. What I'm looking for is kind of an "IntelliSense-capable editor running on Windows Mobile" that lets me write code on my mobile phone wihtout having to power up my laptop.

Comment: Mono's C# compiler is written in C#. It shouldn't be hard to port it to .NET CF (if haven't been done already.)

Comment: Honestly, why would you want to do development on your mobile? That's just asking for pain.

Comment: Depends on your mobile device: http://www.htc.com/de/product/touchpro2/overview.html

Comment: @Mehrdad: this would be MonoDevelop, not the compiler.

Answer (score 2):

Though I'd second the comment about the pain of doing development on your mobile (it would take me just as long to peck out 3 lines on my phone as it would to fire up my laptop), here are two mobile IDEs:

http://www.pocketpcfreeware.com/en/index.php?soft=1989

UPDATE: I removed the second link, because it looks like it's not a .NET IDE. My bad on that one :(

Comment: The first one seems to have an ordinary text box, the second one is not C#-capable. Thank you anyway.

Comment: I downloaded this one, but was greeted with some kind of exception while starting it up. Did not bother to solve this. VS runs reasonably well on my HTC Shift with Vista.